# AppName.exe.config is not generated

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a winforms app. in which I have a configuration file named `App.config`. However, when I run the app using visual studio, the `AppName.exe.config` file is not generated automatically. Usually Visual Studio should automatically convert the `App.config` file to `AppName.exe.config` and copy to bin folder. But it doesn't. I changed the properties for `App.config` file and set the **"Copy to output directory"** property to **"Copy always"**. It solved the problem. but my issue, is the next time I clone the source code from remote repository it doesn't work. I have to go and either rename the `App.config` file to something else and then rename it back to `App.config`, or I have to change the **"Copy to output directory"** property to something else and then change it back to **"Copy always"**. One of these two actions need to be done to trigger the Visual Studio to do the conversion of `App.config` to `AppName.exe.config` otherwise it won't work. Now my concern is that, I worry about the next person that will be working on the source code, as the config file not being copied generates an strange error which is hard to understand is due to missing configuration file. What can I do to make sure the `AppName.exe.config` file will always be generated on the first build after cloning the source code?

Thank you.

I tried changing the "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always". I was expecting it would solve the problem.